# i want to make download link using html form get and post method

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want to make download link using html form get and post method and get a unique download link for every download

```
<form action="website.com" method="post" target="_blank">
<input name="filename" type="hidden" value="File.zip"><br> 
<input name="filesize" type="hidden" value="43.5GB"><br> 
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="188.138.0.0">
<p></p>
<div align="center">
<input alt="Download" height="99" src="button-download.png" type="image" width="184">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: you mean file.zip?time=11258592982

Comment: I think he means a random scrambled one time link?

Comment: What you actually want to achieve here is pretty unclear at the moment. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to describe what it actually is you want in more detail. Plus, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the download link with *anchor* tag and give it your relative path of image as shown below. This may help.

**Updated:**

If you want to make it download then you have to use javascript for that.
I have created code on submit that will click on *anchor* tag and will download your image. This may help.

```
<form action="website.com" method="post" target="_blank" id="form_submit">
   <input name="filename" type="hidden" value="File.zip"><br> 
   <input name="filesize" type="hidden" value="43.5GB"><br> 
   <input name="id" type="hidden" value="188.138.0.0">
   <p></p>
   <div align="center">
      <a download="button-download.png" href="/path/to/image" title="ImageName" id="download_image">
       <img alt="ImageName" src="/path/to/image">
      </a>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#form_submit").submit(function(){
        document.getElementById('download_image').click(); 
   });
});
```

Comment: using form method